# Simple function to display div only if wordpress index is loaded

Tags: php, javascript

I'm just learning the Wordpress structure and javascript/php so I'm hoping someone can help me figure this problem out.

What I'm trying to do is display a div I've placed in my header.php, but only when it's the 'index.php' file that is loaded.

Shouldn't it look like this?

```
$(document).ready(){
    if.this(document == "http://sample.com/") {
        this.document.getElementById('only-show-when-index').style.display = "visible";
    } else {
        this.document.getElementById('only-show-when-index').style.display = "hidden";
    }
};
```

Comment: What's happening now? Is it always showing or never showing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some syntax errors, and you're not in a context where 'this' will work:

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://sample.com/'){
     document.getElementById('only-show-when-index').style.display = "block";
}else{
      document.getElementById('only-show-when-index').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Yay! @fred2 you're amazing. Thanks so much for that super fast response and the tip. It totally works now.

Answer (score 2):

fred2 already addressed the syntax errors nicely. However, since jQuery is already loaded you could use it to make things a little more compact:

```
$(document).ready(){
    if ( window.location.href == "http://sample.com/" ) {
        $('#only-show-when-index').show();
    } else {
        $('#only-show-when-index').hide();
    }
};
```

I'd like to also point out that since you're using WordPress and this will never change without a refresh, you could accomplish the same thing with a bit of PHP around your added code:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ): ?>
    <!-- shown only on front page -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- shown everywhere else -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then you wouldn't be dependent on the user's browser to show/hide your code.

Comment: I plan on using the header function do strategically show a few different scenarios, so I think I'll keep up with the script for now. Thanks anyway though!